# group objects by a field and sum another, then produce a CSV report

Tags: json, csv, jq

How can I create a csv from this json? I have:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "cash": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Anna",
    "cash": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "Anna",
    "cash": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "cash": 8
  }
]
```

I need group by name and sum the cash and send the result a .csv like:

```
John,13
Anna,7
```

Thanks!

Comment: jq -r '[.[] | select(.name)] | map ([.name,.cash]) [] | @csv' data.json > data_grouped.csv

Comment: jq -r '[.[] | group_by(.name)] | map ([.name,.cash]) [] | add | @csv' data.json > data.csv
    jq: error (at data.json:19334): Cannot index string with string "name"

Comment: And other things, but I don't know. In the first, really I have a csv with name, cash lines, and other I have only errors because I don't know how can I group by with sum...

Comment: Those are really valid attempts, add them to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQ has `group_by` as a builtin, use that and do `map(.cash) | add` to sum `cash` values for each group.

```
group_by(.name)[] | [.[0].name, (map(.cash) | add)] | @csv
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CKeDDEj9va)</sup>

Comment: Thanks!! It's running!