# Group and Sum value with JQ

Tags: json, shell, jq

I've got a file with these jsons:

```
{"count":42,"day":"2023-06-22","id":"123"}
{"count":12,"day":"2023-06-22","id":"456"}
{"count":23,"day":"2023-06-23","id":"123"}
{"count":44,"day":"2023-06-23","id":"789"}
{"count":65,"day":"2023-06-21","id":"456"}
```

Actually I don't care about the `day` and want to group my records by `id` and sum the `count`. Expected result:

```
{"id":"123","count":65}
{"id":"456","count":77}
{"id":"789","count":44}
```

How would I achieve this with JQ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [group objects by a field and sum another, then produce a CSV report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953604/group-objects-by-a-field-and-sum-another-then-produce-a-csv-report)

Comment: Yes, that's answering it! Thanks, did not find it myself in search...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group_by` to group the objects.

```
jq -cs 'group_by(.id)[] | {id: .[0].id, count: map(.count) | add}' < file.json
```

- `-s` wraps the whole input into a large array so you can process all the objects instead of iterating them one by one;
- `-c` compresses the output so it looks like the desired one.

Answer (score 3):

If the input is large, and you don't want to `--slurp` (or `-s`) all items into memory (only effective if there are at least some duplicate IDs), you can take a `reduce`-based approach which iterates over the `inputs` collecting only the aggregated values:

```bash
jq -cn '
  reduce inputs as {$count, $id} ({}; .[$id] += $count)
  | to_entries[] | {id: .key, count: .value}
'
```

```json
{"id":"123","count":65}
{"id":"456","count":77}
{"id":"789","count":44}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/raTaXueaQDm)